# Is it possible create a table with n number on mysql? Where n is variable

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio, datagrid

My teamwork have an issue let me explain it.
They have a set of records and they put the data into a datagrid on Visual Studio. The next step is to move the content of the datagrid onto a MySQL database but the headers are the problem because they want to convert them into SQL variables.

Just like this.

```
CREATE TABLE anyname (
      ID not null,
      variable1 (from datagrid) varchar (60),
      .
      .
      .
      variablen (from datagrid) varchar (60)
```

);

is it possible do it?

Comment: What do you want to do here? This is an extremely vague question. Also why would you want a schema like this? It seems like a nightmare to maintain. Additionally is there anything magical about 60? That seems extremely arbitrary and is bound to lead to data truncation.

Comment: While I question why to create lots of tables on the fly and wonder if their might be a more static structure that would work, I would think using the application layer for this task would be better than database layer because the datagrid source already has the structure so figure out how to create table from datatable or whatever the source is.  In SQL this will be far more complicated, but you could create a parameterized stored procedure  and execute dynamic sql to actually create the table which could also open you up to a sql injection attack depending on where parameters are populated

Answer (score 0):

A more general, flexible method would be to make the column number a field in the table, rather than having a separate column for each grid column.

```
CREATE TABLE anyname (
    id NOT NULL,
    rownum INT,
    colnum INT,
    valvalue VARCHAR(60),
    UNIQUE KEY (rownum, colnum)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build the CREATE TABLE for example in python and then execute it. No problem.